# Problem in back key press on android

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app I have 3 activities and I use `onBackPressed` for first, second and third activities.
My need is I want to go from first `activity` -> `second activity` -> `third activity` and
From `third activity` -> `second activity` -> `first activity` -> `finsh()`

I go first activity->second activity->third activity by click buttons

My problems is when I press back key of emulator it comes in the following direction
`Third activity` -> `second activity` -> `first activity` -> `second activity` -> `first activity` -> `first activity` -> and `finsh()`. Instead of `finsh()`, my app goes to `second activity` -> `first activity` -> `first activity`.

How to solve the problem. I do not know where I am wrong. Please help me.
My code:

In first activity:

```
       Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.first);
       b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent myintent=new Intent(first.this,second.class);
         startActivity(myintent);
          }
      });
    ......
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.e("main-back","main-back");
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

In second  activity:

```
    Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.second);
    Log.e("main2", "main2");
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent myintent=new Intent(second.this,third.class);
         startActivity(myintent);
          }
      });        
    ........

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent myintent=new Intent(second.this,first.class);
    startActivity(myintent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

In third activity:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent myintent=new Intent(third.this,second.class);
    startActivity(myintent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop launching activities in the method `onBackPressed` (I am assuming this is the method where you want to finish the current activity).

So in the second and the third activities method `onBackPressed` call `finish()`, just like the first activity `onBackPressed` method.

Comment: For that matter, if that is ALL you have on onBackPressed() just delete that whole block.  It will automatically call finish() for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.second);
    Log.e("main2", "main2");
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent myintent=new Intent(second.this,third.class);
         startActivity(myintent);
          }
      });        

@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    Intent myintent=new Intent(second.this,first.class);
    second.this.finish();
    startActivity(myintent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

just try this.